# Make Intellij Idea plugin work with Kotlin files

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I've created this very simple **Intellij Idea plugin** which folds some reference expressions. It works great for Java files but it doesn't work for Kotlin.

Here is the source: https://github.com/nodes-android/nstack-translation-folding. 
I will include here the important parts:

**plugin.xml**

```
</idea-plugin>
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.all</depends>

    <application-components>
        <component>
            <implementation-class>com.nodes.folding.TranslationFoldingBuilder</implementation-class>
        </component>
    </application-components>

    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <lang.foldingBuilder language="JAVA" implementationClass="com.nodes.folding.TranslationFoldingBuilder"/>
    </extensions>

</idea-plugin>
```

**TranslationFoldingBuilder.kt**

```
class TranslationFoldingBuilder : FoldingBuilderEx() {

    override fun buildFoldRegions(root: PsiElement, document: Document, quick: Boolean): Array<FoldingDescriptor> {
        if (root !is PsiJavaFile) {
            return FoldingDescriptor.EMPTY
        }

        val descriptors = ArrayList<FoldingDescriptor>()
        // Get all the reference expressions in this Java file
        val referenceExpressions = PsiTreeUtil.findChildrenOfType(root, PsiReferenceExpression::class.java)

        // Some logic

        return descriptors.toTypedArray()
    }
}
```

My problem is that for Kotlin files the **buildFoldRegions()** is not called at all.

Comment: Did you try to specify 'language="KOTLIN"'?

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it will not work for kotlin ,as your

> if (root !is PsiJavaFile) {
>               return FoldingDescriptor.EMPTY
>           }

For kotlin files, the file is `org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile` instance, rather than `PsiJavaFile`

---

Update:

1. You need to add kotlin plugin as the dependency of your plugin in *plugin.xml*
2. The psi api of Kotlin is not same as Java (They are different languages). You need to write a different class (but some can be same, I just copy your origin code and edit so there is some duplicate in my kt implementation.

You can see my commit here https://github.com/aristotll/nstack-translation-folding/commit/45286e6ec10d3b50defe25d55f8fbd8f122a148b.

Comment: Thank you for your response but the Kotlin package is not found in `org.jetbrains`. Do I need to import it in `plugin.xml` or maybe in some other place ? I tried to remove that `if` check but it doesn't work for Kotlin files anyway. The `buildFoldRegions()` is not called at all. This is the main problem. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I've added a bounty to this question.

Comment: Your answer is not complete because you didn't mention the most important part, adding the Kotlin plugin classes as jar file to the dependencies. I got help on intellij-support.jetbrains.com. I will post my full answer later and mark it as the accepted one. I appreciate the effort so you can have the points anyway.

Comment: @vovahost I thought you already know it, sorry. And I think maybe you need to use gradle with Intellij plugin to manage the plugin dependencies, like this plugin do https://github.com/dkandalov/live-plugin/blob/dba9ec48bdc73a5b4952bce9e4c4a02218cf2a06/build.gradle#L38-L49

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding `kotlin-compiler` library to the project resolved the issue with missing classes as `KtFile` and other related to *Kotlin Psi*.

Comment: How does one add the `kotlin-compiler` library to an intelliji plugin project?